# How to create a USB Kali UEFI bootable dongle with a exFAT partition

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, uefi, exfat

I'm struggling with the creation of a USB UEFI bootable dongle of kali linux. Basically I want to create a dongle able to boot kali linux in UEFI mode that also has an exFAT partition recognizable by windows. As far as I know Windows recognizes a partition only if it is the first. I tried to create a first exFAT partition and then put kali on a second contigue partition using dd, but it won't boot. Simply it is not recognized among the bootable media by UEFI. Any advice of how to do it in a Linux environment?

Answer (score 1):

Only FAT32 support is guaranteed across all UEFI versions. Newer UEFI versions also include other versions of FAT, but as far as I know, exFAT is not among the versions required to be supported.

*Some* firmware authors *may* have included exFAT support anyway, as the UEFI specification allows firmware authors to add filesystem support above and beyond what is required by the specification.

You said you "put kali on a second contigue partition using dd". Assuming you meant a Kali ISO that has been prepared to also be USB boot compatible (as opposed to being bootable in a CD/DVD form only), writing that ISO image into a partition won't work. Such an ISO image contains its own partition table, and you normally cannot usefully nest partition tables: most operating systems (and certainly UEFI firmware implementations) will expect just one partition table per storage device, with filesystems inside partitions.

For one thing, there is no standard partition type that would mean "this partition contains another partition table and a set of sub-partitions", which is what your setup would need.

I would recommend that you instead begin with writing the bootable ISO to the whole-USB device, then verify that it is in fact bootable, and then use `gparted` or any other partitioning tool to 1.) correct the partition table included in the ISO image to cover the full capacity of the USB device, and 2.) then add an exFAT partition to the free space.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I used the ubuntu utility to wrote the ISO into the whole USB device using the disk creator utility in ubuntu and now I have (over a 64 GB USB drive) the first partition  ISO9660 bootable containing kali linux whose size is 3GB, a second partition EFI (FAT-12/16/32) whose size is 442 KB and 60 GB of unallocated space that I can format with an exFAT file system. Will this last partition be recognizable by windows?

Comment: Without knowing your version of Windows (Home/Pro etc.), any group policies that might be applied to it, and any security software that might be installed to it, I can only say that that's exactly how I would do it and I would fully expect it to work. Note that on first use in Windows, the partition might not have a drive letter assigned to it: you may have to visit Windows Disk Management once to assign a drive letter to the partition.

Comment: You were right. A corect sequence is: write the USB stick using dd or similar, partition the remaining space to use it either to persist data for kali or/and use it as mass storage. Doing that I had a kernel panic at boot. After trying with a different one It turned out I have a faulty USB stick.